# My jquery not selector not working

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").not("a[href~='test']").click(function(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Links', 'click', $(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

The not selector is not working for me. jquery version is 1.11.0

Comment: can you post your HTML also?

Comment: It is for a client of mine. He is using shopify website.

Comment: Why do you say it's not working? Do the elements exist when the code is run? Where is a sample of the html?

Comment: @sivi: So? That doesn't mean you shouldn't quote the HTML you're trying to match / not match.

Comment: Sorry to all. Just found out the issue. They are not linking the full url and that was the problem there. They are just having the relative url.

Comment: Thanks  @charlietfl for asking the question....

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess at it...

Your selector is using `~=`, which [means](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> ...attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to (the value)

My guess is this is not what you meant. If you meant to exclude any `a` element whose `href` **contains** `"test"`, then you wanted `*=`:

```
$("a").not("a[href*='test']").click(/*...*/);
```

If you wanted to exclude ones whose `href` **starts with** `"test"`, you wanted `^=`:

```
$("a").not("a[href^='test']").click(/*...*/);
```

[More in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `~` attribute selector of jquery.
 `[name~="value"]` it says *Attribute Contains Word Selector*

So,

```
$("a").not("a[href~='test']")
```

This will only work for those anchors which has the word `test` *delimited by spaces.*

So it requires something like this type of anchor href:

```
<a href="http://example.com/ test /zy/zy/">link</a>
```

which i guess you don't have in your markup.

```
$("a").not("a[href*='test']")
```

i guess you need to use `*` contains selector.